# Running a local server for javascript but still not able to load favicon images

Tags: javascript, server, xampp, localhost, localserver

I'm running a local server but my console says that it still can't load the images from my system. My images are inside a folder and I'm trying to load it.
I have tried using several servers - xampp, npm node.js, vscode live server, servez and even though my servers are running it does not display the image.

These are the errors,

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
```

and

```
"GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I've been having this issue for a while. I'm trying to work with JavaScript and p5 so I require images from my system. How do I get rid of these errors and be able to load images from my system folder. Thank you, any help is appreciated

Comment: It says "not found", so why do you think it should be found *there*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that in the root project `favicon.ico` file doesn't exist, so grab a copy of `favicon.ico` and put it in your root project directory.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how to do it? I mean I just need a picture there?

Comment: Your project needs an icon file, the `favicon.ico` file. Put it in your root project (should be the same directory as index.html)

Comment: Right I'm not getting that error anymore however I still can't load the images from my system

Comment: Create a folder called `assets` and put your images inside it and refer it to your html or js.

Comment: I'm using p5 library an I'm loading the images using its loadImage function, however putting it in assets folder didn't make it work. In fact I still get an error message in my console saying ```failed to load local resource```

Comment: I just noticed that I'm not able to load my javascript file

Comment: Thank you for your time I was able to figure out how tro solve the problem. ```http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/sketch.js```